# Creating Cab failed with VS2008 In windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, windows-8.1, cab, cabwiz

recently I'm upgrade to windows 8.1.

after trying craete CAB install for one of my old project for windows mobile I get this error:

```
Warning: Section [RegKeys] has no data
Warning: Section [DefaultInstall] key "AddReg" - there are no section entries to process
Error: CAB file "SomePath\Release\FCS Setup.CAB" could not be created
```

and this is the inf file

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Provider="Souren"
CESignature="$Windows CE$"

[CEStrings]
AppName="FCS"
InstallDir=%CE1%\%AppName%

[Strings]
Manufacturer="Souren"

[CEDevice]
VersionMin=4.0
VersionMax=6.99
BuildMax=0xE0000000

[DefaultInstall]
CEShortcuts=Shortcuts
AddReg=RegKeys
CopyFiles=Files.Common1

[SourceDisksNames]
1=,"Common1",,"SomePath\Release\"

[SourceDisksFiles]
"FCS.exe"=1

[DestinationDirs]
Shortcuts=0,%CE2%\Start Menu
Files.Common1=0,"%InstallDir%"

[Files.Common1]
"FCS.exe","FCS.exe",,0


[Shortcuts]
"FCS",0,"FCS.exe","%CE17%"

[RegKeys]
```

after this error I notice the `[RegKeys]` part is empty so add some registery to cab and my last part of inf file change to this :

```
[RegKeys]
"HKCR","FCS","FCSName","0x00000000","SomeName"
```

but still the cab is not create. and error just change to this :

```
Error: CAB file "SomePath\Release\FCS Setup.CAB" could not be created
```

is there something wrong with windows 8.1 and vs 2008? this project work fine in my previous windows.

Answer (score 1):

I found a soltion and it worked for me.
It's actually related with "8.3 file names"

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/66ecc60c-5895-4020-b876-af122b56b058/ce-cab-wizard-error-cab-file-could-not-be-created

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you run into an access restriction for the folder where the cab should be created.

If you have the INF file, you can try to run cabwiz manually (I nvere liked the VS integration) with the inf file and get more about any errors: http://www.hjgode.de/dev/imec/Making%20a%20CAB%20file.htm